# Unknow attribute 'headers ...' during CSV import on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, libreoffice

I have a problem since I try to import my CSV created with Numbers on Mac,

Everything worked before on Ubuntu with LibreOffice,

When I try to import my CSV file I have error

```
unknown attribute 'adress   user_id room_type etc...' for Bien.
```

I think it not detect separators and take the first hearder line rows as one string.

My import function:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    @bien = Bien.create! row.to_hash
    @bien.save
  end 
end
```

I would know how import the file and if I have things to change when I create my CSV on Numbers.

UPDATE
[image: csv]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide `Bien` attributes and first few lines from your CSV file?

Comment: @Leo i update a screenshot of the CSV

Comment: I suspect since your `adress` column has values with commas in them, Numbers probably changed your separator from comma to something else (likely semicolon). See my answer, I think it is applicable https://stackoverflow.com/a/51426119/3477163

Comment: @supremebeing7 That shouldn't be the case though, by default LibreOffice Calc surrounds text fields with quotes and quotes inside the text field are escaped.

Comment: @AntoineWako Providing the screenshot of the content in Calc is nice and all. But could you also provide the resulting CSV (not a screenshot, but as plain text code block)? The result may vary based on the chosen CSV settings in LibreOffice.

Comment: @JohanWentholt The question specified that this was created with Numbers on Mac. But you may be right about surrounding fields with quotes and escaping. I still think the underlying issue is that the file is using some other separator besides a comma.

Comment: @AntoineWako A bit of advise, you only need `Bien.create! row.to_hash` inside the block, this instantiates and saves the record and raises an error if it doesn't. This means you can leave out variable assignment and the `.save` call. See the [`create!` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're exactly right, it looks like the separators are not being respected so the header row is showing as one long string. To debug, you can try putting a `pry` in and running `CSV.read(file.path)` to see the whole output of the conversion to CSV. Once you do that, you should be able to see what Numbers uses for separators.

[This post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7016794) suggests Numbers uses semicolons as default separators, so if you define your `col_sep: ';'` as an option, that might do the trick. (Ref: [CSV docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new)).

So, the code would be

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, col_sep: ';', headers: true) do |row|
    @bien = Bien.create! row.to_hash
    @bien.save
  end 
end
```

Comment: I saw the separators was spaces so i change separators with LibreOffice and now its work Thanks !